# Zeus server doesn't redirect on RewriteCond HTTP_USER_AGENT rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zeus

I can't get this redirect to function:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad|iPod|iPhone|Android|s+Mobile
RewriteRule .* mobile.php
```

I'm testing it using my Android phone, and also using the user-agent switcher in Google Chrome dev version.

I tried `AllowOverride All` but it makes the server, running Zeus, reply with an access denied message.

It is a shared host and so I do not really have access to any server logs that I know about.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect mobile browsers

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPad.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Android.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackBerry.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackberry.example.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*IEMobile.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ie.example.com [R=301]
```

Comment: Nice list, s+Mobile is also relevant - this targets devices that are not android/ipad/iphone or just mobile browsers that run on multiple oses

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was running Zeus... not apache. It doesn't support .htaccess.

see: [How can I rewrite URLs in the Zeus web server for Mobile useragent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091721/how-can-i-rewrite-urls-in-the-zeus-web-server)