# How can I rewrite URLs in the Zeus web server for Mobile useragent?

Tags: url-rewriting, zeus

I need to redirect anyone with a mobile user agent to a file called mobile.php.
My web hosting provider, Net Registry uses the Zeus web server.

Here's the script I've written from my research

```
RULE_1_START:
# get the document root
map path into SCRATCH:DOCROOT from /
match IN:User-Agent into $ with iPad|iPod|iPhone|Android|s+Mobile

if matched then
    set OUT:Location = /mobile.php
endif
RULE_1_END:
```

I used the [instructions on my host's site](http://www.netregistry.com.au/support/articles/drupal-clean-urls-rewrite#Zues).

I pasted that into their console and it has worked to do redirects. Net registry have some odd console thing that you submit and it takes 10 minutes to update the zeus server config (annoying as hell).

Anyway my issue is that it redirects me to the wrong location:
So if you visit the site, with a user agent string that contains `ipad|ipod|android|\s+mobile` then you will trigger it ()

It takes me here:

```
http://example.com.au/mobile.php,%20catalog/index.php
```

I can't work out how to fix that, or why that happens because at the moment this file exists:

```
http://example.com.au/mobile.php
```

as does this one:

```
http://example.com.au/index.php. Contents of this file are:

<?php header("Location: catalog/index.php");
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work more like an apache .htaccess url Rewrite?

[the official Zeus documentation](http://support.zeus.com/zws/media/docs/4.3/ZWSUserGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing

```
   set OUT:Location = /mobile.php
```

to

```
   set URL = /mobile.php
```

From the manual...
Using Request Rewrite Scripts
To use the request rewriting functionality, create a script in the Zeus Request 
Rewrite Scripting Language.  The script contains instructions telling the 
Virtual Server how to change the URL or headers of requests that match specified criteria.
The Virtual Server compiles the script, and (if the rewrite functionality is 
enabled) uses it every time it receives a request.  It runs the commands in the 
script, changing the URL if it matches the specified criteria.  Once the script is 
finished, the Virtual Server continues processing the resulting URL.Zeus Web Server 4.3 User Guide
142 Configuring URL Handling
When changing the URL, the rewrite functionality can only change the local 
part of it, that is, the part of the URL after the host name.  For example, if a 
user requests http://www.myhost.com/sales/uk.html, the rewrite 
functionality can only make changes to /sales/uk.html.  This means that 
you cannot use the rewrite functionality to change the request to refer to a 
file on another Virtual Server.
For example, the following script illustrates how to change requests for any 
HTML files in the /sales directory so that the user receives them from the 
/newsales directory instead:
match URL into $ with ^/sales/(.*).html
if matched set URL=/newsales/$1.html
The rewrite functionality can also change the HTTP headers that were received 
with a request, and create new HTTP headers to be returned to the user.  For 
example, the following script changes the HTTP host header, so that a request 
for www.mysite.com/subserver is redirected to the Subserver 
www.subserver.mysite.com:
match URL into $ with ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$
if matched then
    set IN:Host = www.$1.mysite.com
    set URL = /$2
endif